# Long loading time after creating Availability Groups and migrating in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

so I have this issue. Our client using MS SQL databases. Two months ago they migrated their databases to the **SQL Enterprise 2019** from earlier version and **Standard edition**.
They major reason was to secure high availability through feature in MS SQL - Availability groups.

After that our application get really slowed. In the simply way to tell, customer startup an app select workspace and then its takes like 15 seconds to load data.
First step is just sending request to database to select data - no inserts, deletes or any high performance processes.
App is using and working with geographical and geometry data, every geo objects is saved in database as **geometry** data type. The first huge, major select is causing the slow issue.

When I was looking at activity mon under wait categories is only one thing suspicious to me and its type **Other**.
[image]

In database I dont see any high cost queries and availability group mode is set to **synchronous**.
If Im getting this right, the synchronous mode should not be the cause of this problem because this database is clearly for reading a data not as I mentioned modifying.

I made changes to some instance parameters and set **Optimize for Ad hoc workloads** to **True** and and **threshold for parallelism** from **5** to **20**.
Other thing which I tried was create a new app source database and database which contains geo data inside of that SQL instance and didnt add them to availability groups.
From application we are using, for test causes, a connection to the one instance with new test databases.

Neither of this settings work. So guys if you have any idea or any experience with this please help me.

Here is a screen of top 10 waits from sys dmv.
[image: Waits from sys dmv]

Comment: Resolving a performance issue would require details of the *actual* query and tables involved and the actual execution plan using PasteThePlan. Optimize for ad hoc won't play a part in actual query performance and parallelism threshold, while upping from 5 is recommended, is not something you would do for a specific query. What debugging have you attempted, have you analyzed waits, network performance etc?

Comment: Thanks @Stu for a quick reply! I edited my question and add screen from sys dmv of waits from sys.dm_os_wait_stats. I found some information by myself that its waits by AV groups waiting to do smthing. Others is kinda hard to me to understand.
Im not really good at this if you can take a look I would appreciate that!
And as I was told, the network should not be a problem but in that area I cant take a look because its in care of the customer but it should by OK.

Comment: When you get wait stats, you should filter out the benign waits (such as hadr_work_queue, : (Books Online description: “AlwaysOn Availability Groups background worker thread waiting for new work to be assigned. This is an expected wait when there are ready workers waiting for new work, which is the normal state.”) > I suggest using the waits query in Glenn Berry's script: https://glennsqlperformance.com/resources/

Comment: I'll echo Stu's comment, since you haven't included any information that can be used to help you out here: please include an example of a query that is running slow, the table definitions involved, and the actual execution plan in your question.

Comment: What earlier version of SQL were you before upgrading to 2019 enterprise? When upgrading did you keep the compatability level to match your previous version? What is the current compat level? One more thing to rule out is the HADR being synchronous; it's easy to change to asynchronous using SSMS, can you test and confirm your specific query is still slow.

Comment: We also still need the actual execution plan of the slow query using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: This kind of question might get more traction [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SMM: it will get traction here in the OP posts the query, schema and plans

Comment: Knowing the answer to @Stu's question is really important here. I *suspect* you have upgraded from 2012, or prior, and thus are having "problems" with the new cardinality estimator. Some queries do run slower in the new one, but these also tends to be less well written queries. This article (and those linked within it) by Grant Fritchey might be useful to you: [Query Store as an Upgrade Tool](https://www.scarydba.com/2021/03/22/query-store-as-an-upgrade-tool/)

Answer (score -1):

**1 - Stats recompute...**

When you are going from a SQL version to a higher one, you must first change the compatibility level (to have some performance benefits) and then recompute all statistics in the database with a FULLSCAN. Why ? Because each version of SQL Server come with a new optimizer that have new operators, new algorithms and many improvements... To stick to this new version of the optimizer the method of computing statistics and the form of the results of these calculations, is rethought with each modification of the engine ... so much so that if we use the old statistics with a new engine, it is like taking the census of the population in 1930, to plan the construction of roads, schools and hospitals for the current actual population ....

**2 - SQL Server Editions...**

When upscaling SQL Server from Standard to Enterprise, you need to increase the "hardware" (even if it is a VM) because many of the features that runs under Enterprise version, and does not exists in Standard, needs some more computationnal resources. As an example, using the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC will use automatically one more thread to the detriment of other processes... In comparison, using a Rolls Royce or a Hummer, instead of a VolksWagen is arguably more comfortable, faster ... but requires more oil and more expensive insurance!

**3 - Synchronous AVG...**

Synchronous AlwaysOn availability groups must have a very fast and faultless network .... If this is not the case, the replication of update requests can drag performance down, especially if you are in pessimistic lockdown (default mode).

**4 - Transaction logs...**

One common global lack of performances can be the latency to write the transaction log.

**5 - Tempdb files...**

Another current global lack of performances can be the latency to access tempdb files.

For those two file problems, use the Glenn Berry latency file query that will give you a indice... Good values are under 7 ms for reads and 15 ms for writes...

**CONCLUSION**

Many other factors can contribute to slow down you system. But without no more information, we cannot help you...